# How to limit the amount of CPU cores used in a python library?

Tags: python, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib, librosa

I am running a DataPipeline for a TensorFlow model (own code, not tf.Data) with an adjustable amount of parallel computations using the multiprocessing library. Although limiting the number of parallel processes (#CPU), I noticed a very high CPU load (significantly above 100%*#CPU).

I tracked the problem down to the librosa library which I use to calculate audio features.

Example code:

```
import librosa
while True:
    librosa.feature.mfcc(y=np.random.normal(0, 1, (26783, )), sr=16000, n_mfcc=24, win_length=640, hop_length=640, n_fft=640)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```

The simple minimum example code snippet above will use around 2000% - 3000% of a single CPU on my machine as shown in htop, which is because librosa seems to parallelize that operation internally.
Since the high CPU load affects my co-workers and takes my control over the CPU load I consume, I want to force the computation to run on a single (or at least controllable amount of) cores.

I imagine something like:

```
limit_cpu_cores_for_this_process(os.getpid())
librosa.feature.mfcc(y=np.random.normal(0, 1, (26783, )), sr=16000, n_mfcc=24, win_length=640, hop_length=640, n_fft=640)
```

to call inside the loop (in the minimum example) or my child process that is supposed to use only one CPU core, but I was unable to find something regarding that very specific topic. In the end, every solution that limits the CPU use of above code (slowing it down is fine to some degree) will help!

As librosa does this internally, I have no possibility to limit the CPU core count directly, but I have to limit code, that is already parallelized by s.o. else.

---

Edit: found the solution myself, see my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, which actually comes from joblib directly (although hard to find).

The following will not only execute with roughly 20% of a single CPU core. On top of that, it is faster (110ms vs 140ms on my machine for one iteration with 100ms sleep time. That's a 4x lower computation time). I guess this is because the audio portions to process are relatively small and the overhead in parallelization is bigger.

```
from threadpoolctl import threadpool_limits
while True:
    with threadpool_limits(limits=1):
        librosa.feature.mfcc(y=np.random.normal(0, 1, (26783, )), sr=16000, n_mfcc=24, win_length=640, hop_length=640, n_fft=640)
    time.sleep(0.1)
```